# Angular Service - Observable is missing properties

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to get this HTTP get call to work. I have seen many examples of get requests for arrays and tried adapting one to just a single object (a user profile) but to no success. I get this error:
[image]

profile.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Profile } from '../models/profile.class';    

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfileService {    

  apiURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }    

  getProfile(userId: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('id', userId); // create new HttpParams    

    return this.httpClient.get<Profile>(`${this.apiURL}/user`, {params})
    .pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        const profile: Profile = new Profile( data.object.id,
                               data.object.info.username,
                               data.object.info.password,
                               data.object.info.fname,
                               data.object.info.lname,
                               data.object.info.email,
                               data.object.joined );
        return profile;
      })
    );
   }
}
```

profile.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../services/profile.service';
import { Profile } from '../models/profile.class';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {    

  profile: Profile;    

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {
  }    

  ngOnInit() {
  }    

  getProfile() {
    this.profile = this.profileService.getProfile( "5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898" );
  }    

}
```

***NOTE: I have read all relevant posts on SO already (including the one that coincidentally also deals with a getProfile API call) and could not figure out my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you don't get a `Profile` when you call `this.profileService.getProfile( "5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898")`
Instead, you get Observable.

So, you have two ways to solve this:

```
  // #1
  async getProfile() {
    this.profile = await this.profileService.getProfile("5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898").toPromise();
  }

  // #2
  getProfile() {
    this.profileService.getProfile("5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898").subscribe(
      profile => this.profile = profile,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Wow, put a lot of effort into that question and the answer was so simple...

Comment: don't transform an observable into a promise. use second option, or transform your this.profile parameter in Observable and use async pipe in template